# String similarity for longer text (searching for words in sentences) in R

Tags: r, text, text-mining, similarity

I need to find a computationally efficient way of identifying and matching words in sentences. I know there are various string similarity packages which uses methods like Levenshtein distance, Jaccard distance, cosine etc like [stringdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html). But these are efficient at approximating the level of similarity of two strings which are approximately the same length. Basically I have to compare short strings with longer ones.

I think it would be best illustrated through an example, I have the description `SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR` and I want to identify whether it belongs to the brand `JOE'S VALLEY` products. For instance, doing a Levenshteins similarity between these two strings will yield a poor similarity. However, if I decide to substring and use only `JOS VALEY` as the description, the similarity score will be greater and acceptable to match.

```
library(stringdist)

# Decription we want to search
sku <- "SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR"
# An established brand in our database
br <- "JOE'S VALLEY"
# For comparison below, this is the misspelled brand in the actual description above
sku_br <- "JOS VALEY" 
# Similarity measures 
methods <- c("osa", "lv", "dl", "hamming", "lcs", "qgram", "cosine", "jaccard", "jw", "soundex")

# Test similarity scores methods
for(i in 1:length(methods)){
     cat(paste0(methods[i],":\n"))
     cat(paste0(sku," <-> ",br," ====> ",stringsim(sku,br,method = methods[i]),"\n"))
     cat(paste0(sku_br ," <-> ",br," ====> ",stringsim(sku_br,br,method = methods[i]),"\n"))
     cat(paste0("\n"))
 }
```

In case you can not run the code above, here is the output:

```
osa:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.175
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.75

lv:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.175
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.75

dl:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.175
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.75

hamming:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0

lcs:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.346153846153846
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.857142857142857

qgram:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.423076923076923
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.857142857142857

cosine:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.649519052838329
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.916666666666667

jaccard:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.428571428571429
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.9

jw:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.624494949494949
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0.805555555555555

soundex:
SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 0
JOS VALEY <-> JOE'S VALLEY ====> 1
```

From the results above we can see that the full sku description doesn't match up well with the compared brand. However, if we substring the misspelled brand it obtained an acceptable matching score.

So one solution I have is creating a 'search window' that iterates through the entire full description (search window length is equal to the length of the brand string). For example, it will start by computing the similarity between:

1. `SPECIAL JOS`  and `JOE'S VALLEY` then if score is less than tolerance it will increment the window one character up.
2. `PECIAL JOS V` compare `JOE'S VALLEY` then if score is less ...
3. `ECIAL JOS VA` compare `JOE'S VALLEY` then if score is less ...
   up until the point where it will obtain a score that is more than the required tolerance, it will return a match.

This is very computationally expensive and is excacerbated by the number of brands in our database. So my question is, is there a more efficient way of doing it this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Maybe the window does not need to move by character, but by word?

Comment: This will definitely work for most cases (in my data) - problem is sometimes the descriptions will not have spacing between them (where there is supposed to be one). For example, 'SPECIALJOESVALLEY CHOC COOKIES 10X550GR". Using a one-word window would then have to compare "SPECIALJOESVALLEY CHOC" with "JOE'S VALLEY", which will return a poor similarity. Nonetheless, it's definitely one of my last options, I'll just have to sacrifice these rare cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If have a good prior on the common typos you may be able to use regex.  example:

```
sku <- "SPECIAL JOS VALEY CHOCK COOKIES 10X550GR"
joes_valley_regex <- "JOE?'?S\\s+VALL?[EA]Y"

grepl(joes_valley_regex,sku)
```

Comment: Good idea thanks, I just don't know how feasible it is to apply regex on the entire database ie list of brands (and whether it is sustainable going forward).

Comment: I think your idea of finding the minimum string distance in the set of all substrings of length equal to the input string (e.g. 'br') sounds workable but like you noted is compute expensive.  If you can come up with a regex for every brand it would work as well but unless you capture all possible typos/misspellings it wouldn't work well and you need to keep maintaining the regex list.

Comment: There may be a way to auto-generate the regex from corpora of misspellings/typos (more work up front). [here](http://trimc-nlp.blogspot.com/2013/07/auto-generation-of-regular-expressions.html) and [here](https://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~roger/corpora.html)